# Marking variables within Angular2 components as global (for debugging)

Tags: typescript, angular

Setting variables as global (temporarily) is useful for debugging. How do we mark a variable within an Angular component as global so that it could be interactively used within the browser web console? (I don't want to just log the variable with `console.log` but have the ability to interact with and use the variable from within the javascript web console.

```
@Component({..})
export class App {
    myvar = null;
    constructor() {
      this.myvar = "Hello World";
    }

      // How do we make myvar global? (temporarily)
      // so that we can use it in the web console to play around with it
      // It's a simple string here but it could be a complex object
      // that we may want to inspect interactively.

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bypass TypeScript's complaints with `any` and attach to `window` like you would with normal JavaScript.

```
constructor() {
    this.myvar = "Hello console";

    (window as any).myvar = this.myvar; //DEBUG
}
```